# Sinusoidal Current in a Saddle PWM BLDC Motor

Tags: motor, pwm, brushless-dc-motor

I have learned that many BLAC motors have a saddle-shaped phase voltage. Apparently, this can improve efficiency while still retaining the sinusoidal line-line waveform. One reference for this is here: [Digikey Three Phase Brushless Motor Control](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/why-and-how-to-sinusoidally-control-three-phase-brushless-dc-motors)

However, it is also claimed that the phase current remains sinusoidal for this phase voltage. I cannot see how this is possible. If we assume no phase inductance, the phase voltage equation looks like this:
\$V_p = IpR_p + bemf_p\$

I have constructed the saddle waveform in matlab, along with an arbitrary sinusoidal back-emf. I have plotted these here:
[image: Back EMF and applied phase voltage]
I have also plotted the difference of these waves to determine the phase current:
[image: Difference]
What I have found is clearly not a sine wave, or anything close to one. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Plot all 3 phases and then plot the differences between them.

Comment: I did this, and I agree the line-line voltage is the sine wave. What I am not seeing is why the phase current is a sine wave.

Comment: @Nathan At any given time, two PWM driven phases are sourcing current into the motor windings and one grounded phase is sinking current. So you can't estimate the current by just taking the difference of two (driven) phase voltages, you need to consider the remaining (grounded) third phase as well.

Answer (score 3):

A conceptually simple approach to driving a three phase motor is to simultaneously apply three sinusoidal voltages to the three phases. If you drive a motor this way, the phase voltages look like normal sinusoids relative to ground and the star point of the motor remains at a constant voltage.

However, a more efficient way to do it is to ground one of the phases and drive the two remaining phases with sinusoidal voltages. Normal drive topologies only let you apply positive voltages relative to ground, so this of course limits the commutation range to only 120 (electrical) degrees, not the 360 required. However, you can get around this limitation by just switching which of the three phases is grounded three times per (electrical) rotation. When you do the math, you end up with those weird saddle shaped waveforms relative to ground, but if you plot the phase voltages relative to the motor star point instead of ground, you will see that they are indeed sinusoidal, not saddle shaped.

Comment: What are you considering to be ground in this case?

Comment: @Nathan You have three motor phases, each driven by its own transistor half bridge. The half bridges are supplied with a DC voltage, called the DC bus or DC link. Ground (0 V) would be the negative side of that DC bus. I might add a simplified schematic of a typical motor driver to my answer tomorrow (unless someone else comes up with a better answer), as well as a more comprehensive explanation

Comment: Do you mean the diodes are allowed to free-wheel? I am not sure I understand how you would pull the phase to ground in a half-bridge.

Comment: @Nathan You pull a phase low (to ground) by turning on that phases low side transistor. The diode in parallel with said transistor won’t turn on in typical operation. They can turn on under transient conditions (such as when a phase transitions from being driven with PWM to being pulled low / grounded). The diodes may also conduct when the motor is braking (back-EMF is higher than applied voltage), especially if the motor driver uses BJT or IGBT transistors instead of MOSFETs (MOSFETs will also conduct backwards when on, preventing the voltage from rising enough to forward bias the diode)

Comment: I appreciate all your help with this. Do you know of a reference for the derivation of the voltage from phase to neutral?